# Highcharts Zoom out in steps

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts time series currently we are able to zoom in data and we can reset zoom through button but i want something that can zoom out in steps in same manner like how we zoom in. Is there any way? Any help would be great.Thanks in advance

Comment: To help get better answers to your question, please include a code sample or link to where we can see the code you've created so far.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find, after zooming selection, new xAxis extremes, and keep them in extremesXmin and extremesXmax arrays, then set these previous extremes after clicked resetZoomButton:

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
      selection: function(e) {
        if (e.xAxis) {
          extremesXmin.push(e.xAxis[0].min)
          extremesXmax.push(e.xAxis[0].max)
        }
        zoomLevel++;
      }
    }
  },
```

To control the button and set new extremes, you need to overwrite zoomOut() function inside showResetZoom() function inside Highcharts prototype:

```
function zoomOut() {
  if (zoomLevel > 1) {
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremesXmin[extremesXmin.length - 2], extremesXmax[extremesXmax.length - 2])
    extremesXmin.pop()
    extremesXmax.pop()
    zoomLevel--;
  } else {
    chart.zoomOut();
  }
}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h8af7L9g/

Comment: In the code i see u have set lang parameter. What is the use of the same and what is the alternative of it ?

Comment: Please help here... The logic too has loophole it doesnt work properly.. For example In the fiddle it works fine the first time but once u r back to the original place and then u just zoom in once and then try reset zooming instead of coming back to the original it zooms out to other position.

Comment: So i figured this out, It is happening because of the chart.zoomout function this is somehow manipulating zoomLevel to not be 0 and so this issue. But if i dont call that function the button is not getting hidden.
So the only thing left in your previous approach was to hide the button on setting zoomlevel to 0.